# ROC curve representation in paper

Tags: machine-learning, roc, auc

Recently I crossed a [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11265-021-01644-4), which authors presented their ROC curve results in the following way:

> 44,7,0,19,18,74,15,8,27,24,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
> 0,0,0,183,42,36,46,59,25,6,2,2,15,330,81,59,86,1
> 04,14,2,2,2,8,16,4,2,2,8,317,97,67,67,86,287,89,5
> 9,59,80,359,104,67,86,102,16,4,2,2,8,16,4,2,2,8,1
> 78,62,31,40,45,336,98,65,84,89,31,23,8,0,0,2,2,0,
> 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,13,324,0,114,0,0,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,
> 265,0,0,0,0,0,0,12,0,57,21,0,0,156,121,6,361,0

How can understand the performance over the used dataset?
I checked this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/105577/240550) and [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28745/advantages-of-roc-curves) but still I don't get it how it can be represented instead of scores by above numbers?

Comment: I'll state the obvious and point out that this is a dump of numbers and not ROC curves. I was going to suggest to get in touch with the authors before I noticed that the email for contact is 13121239987@163.com.

Comment: @dipetkov many researchers in China use email addresses in the 163.com domain. They are all numbers, this one looks fairly legit.

Comment: @Calimo Thanks. Then the author might appreciate to learn that something went wrong with Figure 4 of his paper because this doesn't look like a legit ROC curve.

Comment: Absolutely. And I would also take the rest of the paper with a grain of salt, as something obviously went very wrong in the peer review process...